# Quick way to empty a partition

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, ext4

I have a partition, formatted ext4, that I want to empty completely.  I will be repeating this write-then-empty process repeatedly, so I want the emptying step to be as quick as possible.

One option is to:

$ rm -rf *

But if the partition has lots of files and big ones, I've found it can take a significant amount of time.

Another option is to unmount the partition and reformat it, but I definitely prefer not taking this approach.

So, my question: Is there another way to empty a partition short of re-formatting it or traversing down the tree with rm -rf *?

Comment: Voting to move as not a programming quetion

Answer (score 0):

To write zeros to a partition (e.g. /dev/sda2/) try the following

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=1M
```

or write random data to partition

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda2 bs=1M
```

Comment: You can double check if its empty with
`dd if=/dev/sda2 | hexdump -C | grep [^00]`

Comment: This would require unmounting the partition, right?  Also, using dd would be much slower than just reformatting the partition.

Comment: Yes it would. Another possible solution would be to use `find . -type f -delete` This is a faster and more robust approach to delete files without having to unmount a partition.

Comment: How is "find . -type f -delete" different from "rm -rf *"?  Would it be faster?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it's faster but it is. I've read somewhere that its to do which buffer sizes but I don't quite understand it. If you want to run your own benchmarks, prefix your command with `time`